# rails devsie_ldp how to ignore certificate verification?

Tags: devise, ldap, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using devise, devise_ldap_authenticatable module to do simple ldap authentication.
But if I try to authenticate on ssl (689 port), I have this error:

```
Net::LDAP::Error (hostname "x.x.x.x" does not match the server certificate):
```

So, I need to ignore this verification.
I tried to google, but I have no result :( 
How I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [devise_ldap_authenticatable documentation](https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable/blob/904a64fd1f196d5ddf02874642657822dbaaf1e5/README.md#troubleshooting)

> If you're using a test LDAP server running a self-signed SSL certificate, make sure the appropriate root certificate is installed on your system. Alternately, you may temporarily disable certificate checking for SSL by modifying your system LDAP configuration (e.g., /etc/openldap/ldap.conf or /etc/ldap/ldap.conf) to read TLS_REQCERT never.